# Find git branch that got pushed to a bare repository

Tags: git

Lets have 2 repositories, one containing the actual data repo and a bare repository which is loaded with deltas from the actual data repository by doing a git push from data repo to bare repo. Hope you have understood the model that am using here.

Am creating clones by cloning the bare repo, and i will be pushing from the branches in my local clone to the branches in bare repository. When am pushing data from my branch to bare repo, the data is automatically synced to the data repo by a hook.

The question i have - is there a way to find from which branch a code has come to the bare repo. I can see the source and target branch during a git push, but after pushing can i see from logs or other way to identify from which branch and repository the data has been pushed from? If there are 5 developers pushing to bare repo, can i find in the bare repo from which branch and clone a code is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

[The simplest way](http://learn.github.com/p/log.html#branch_graph): `git log --pretty=oneline --graph`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this command and i got the graph, but it doesnt show the different branch names that got pushed from the clones to the bare repository. It shows the commit and the comments but not the different branch names. :(

Answer (score 0):

`gitg` might be a decent solution for this, since it will show you the history with markers pointing to the head of each branch.